# How to remove first and last N rows in a dataframe using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` of 2M+ rows that looks like this:

```
        LOCUS POS COUNT
1: CP007539.1   1     4
2: CP007539.1   2     7
3: CP007539.1   3    10
4: CP007539.1   4    15
5: CP007539.1   5    21
6: CP007539.1   6    28
```

Currently I am using this in order to remove the first and last 1000 rows:

```
> df_adj = df[head(df$POS,-1000),]
> df_adj = tail[(df_adj$POS,-1000),]
```

But even I can see that this can be done in a better way. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this specifying the range of rows you want to leave in the final dataset:

```
 df_adj <- df[1001:( nrow(df) - 1000 ),]
```

Just make sure you have enough rows to perform this. A safer approach might be:

```
df_adj <- if( nrow(df) > 2000 ) df[1001:( nrow(df) - 1000 ),] else df
```

Comment: The colon creates a vector of ordered numbers. E.g. 5:8 creates 5,6,7,8. So I am selecting rows 1001:(number of rows of dataframe minus 1000), which is in effect removing the first 1000 rows and last 1000 rows.

Comment: And why do you use `I()`?  I'd tried just  `df[1001:{nrow(df)-1000}, ]` and it still did the job.

Comment: I was scared if I didn't put `I()` that it would erroneously select `1001:nrow(df)`, and ignore the `-1000` part. It seems, however, that if you just surround in parentheses it works, and `I()` is not needed, as you taught me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to combine `seq_len` with `nrow` and `range`:

```
df <- head(iris, 10)      
df[-range(seq_len(nrow(df))), ]
```

which will generate the output below:

```
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
# 8          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
```